# "I feel like such a fool" Possible?

Tags: grammaticality

I was thinking, is it grammatically correct to say, "**I feel like such a fool**"?

In my opinion it can be either "*I feel like a fool*" or "*I feel such a fool*".

Comment: You are likely to hear native English speakers using all three - although not at the same time! However, I agree with your preferences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There appears to be a difference in usage between British vs. American English for this sense of *feel*. British English uses "feel such a" and American English (the dialect I speak) uses "feel like such a". And both dialects use "feel like a".

This is backed up by the data I found using the British National Corpus (BNC) and the Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA):

BNC:

- "feel like such a": no relevant results
- "feel such a": 8 relevant results
- "feel like a": 224 results, but not all are relevant (and I don't feel like getting an exact number)

COCA:

- "feel like such a": 31 relevant results
- "feel such a": 1 relevant result
- "feel like a": 2791 results, but not all are relevant (and I really don't feel like getting an exact number as this is even larger than the BNC results)

Note: When I say "relevant results", this means I have excluded irrelevant results from the totals, such as "I feel such a connection".